# What VR app that cure myopia?

Tags: eye, technology, cure, myopia-nearsightedness, therapy

Is there an app that can cure myopia, or provide therapy to exercise the eye to focus on objects that "seem" like a certain distance?

Comment: There's none that cures.

Answer (score 2):

## There isn't an app that 'cures' myopia

There is at least one 'eye training' VR app for things like amblyopia (which I make no claim about the benefits or drawbacks of); and [reports from 2015](https://qz.com/489048/an-entrepreneur-is-using-virtual-reality-headsets-to-try-to-cure-vision-disorders/) of a company set up to do something similar:

> But the company is about a third of the way through an extensive nine-month trial involving 50 to 60 participants at the University of California San Francisco to study the effects of See Vividly’s software, Vivid Vision. [...] Earlier this year, a small trial in Slovakia saw improvement in nine of 15 participants with amblyopia.

However, there doesn't seem to be an app for myopia specifically. The closes thing is a [proposed solution to adjust a VR headset's projection so that someone with myopia can see the images projected clearly](http://www.rectifeye.com/files/rectifeye_abstract.pdf) (PDF).